# How can I fix a small puncture hole in vinyl flooring?

Tags: repair, vinyl-flooring

When I was installing mini blinds in my new house, a pair of needle nose pliers fell out of my tool belt and landed nose first into the vinyl floor below.  It left a very small pin sized hole in the floor, you would only notice it if you were looking for it.

Normally I would ignore something like this but my wife is rather upset about it and wants me to fix it if possible.

If there were some kind of plasticized shiny brown goo that I could just dab there then it would completely disappear, but I am unaware of such a material that would be appropriate *(the floor is multiple shades of brown)*.

I don't think replacing a whole square section of vinyl is an appropriate fix for such a small area of damage either and the patch will probably be more noticeable than the hole.  Do you guys have any ideas on how I can McGuyver this floor repair?

Answer (score 1):

A dab of caulking might do it. Look for your color at your local hardware store.